# I can't add subitems to a ListView using more than one Button

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to make some note app for myself.
I can successfully get the course name, start date, end date and worked hours.
The problem is when I click the stop Button, I can't figure out how to add other data to same row but to the different columns.

[image: This is it. I cant add the end date and difference of the two time]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    note.nameofcourse = textBox1.Text;
    item.Text = note.nameofcourse;
    listView1.Items.Add(item);

    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    note.dateofstart = date.ToString();
    item.SubItems.Add(note.dateofstart);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime time_2 = DateTime.Now;
    note.dateofend = time_2.ToString();

    convertit();
}

public void convertit()
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(note.dateofstart);
    DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(note.dateofend);
    TimeSpan totalsum = d2.Subtract(dt);
    note.totalsum = totalsum.ToString();
    //item.SubItems.Add(note.totalsum);
}
```

Also this is my `class.cs`:

```
class noteInfos
{
    public string nameofcourse;
    public string dateofstart;
    public string dateofend;
    public string totalsum;
}
```

Comment: ListView is much more awkward to work with than e.g. DataGridView; make a datatable with the relevant columns, bind it to the DGV (datasource property on the DGV) and then add rows to the table and they will appear in the grid

Comment: Also, please see - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Thank you for your informative answers. I am quite new to logic of OOP. Thats gonna help me for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem somehow. First of all you should create the row if you dont even add something. Then you can edit these rows with that last piece of code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        note.nameofcourse = textBox1.Text;
        item.Text = note.nameofcourse;
        listView1.Items.Add(item);

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        note.dateofstart = date.ToString();
        item.SubItems.Add(note.dateofstart);
        item.SubItems.Add(note.dateofend);
        item.SubItems.Add(note.totalsum);
    }
```

Then i add some weird things too.

```
                int sayi = listView1.Items.Count;
                listView1.Items[sayi -1].SubItems[2].Text = note.dateofend;
                listView1.Items[sayi -1].SubItems[3].Text = note.totalsum;
                note.totalsum = "";
                note.dateofend = "";
```